# How to retrieve data from two related tables using cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables in a database, one as event(eventID,name,location), and the other one as eventImages(id,eventID,path).

I need to get the images related to each event

I have tried the following statement in CakePHP:

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppModel','Model');
   class EventImages extends AppModel {
      public $belongsTo = array('Event' => array('className' => 'Event','foreignKey' => 'eventID'));
 }
```

but no data is retrieved in the controller any missing statement?

Comment: There is no query in the question. `no data is retrieved` - by what find call? It generates what sql, with what result? The code in the question helps, but doesn't explain what you're currently doing, or currently seeing.

Comment: @AD7six i have 2 table first is the event table and each event have images that are saved in the eventImages table, i want to retrieve the images related to each event in the event controller

Comment: That's nice but does not address anything in my comment, or add anything that isn't already in the question.

Comment: @AD7six really so forget about it

Comment: I'm assuming something is unclear. I asked for : 1) the [find call](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) 2) The query (that means sql) - easy to do with [debug kit](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#debug-kit) 3) The actual return value of your find call. What matters to readers is what you are doing, not the code you think might be relevant. Until you add these things to the question - _by editing it_ - the most readers can do is guess what you're doing and therefore what the problem is, nobody should be guessing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define relation in Event model

```
 public $hasMany = array('EventImages'=>array('className'=> 'EventImages', 'foreignKey'=>'eventID') //for multiple image
```

According to naming convention in cakephp Model name should be singular. Also you have to define public $primarykey = 'eventID' in Event model as cakephp by default use id field as primary key.